# Teamviewer password has expired?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, teamviewer

I am trying to access my home computer while traveling.  The teamviewer password that I set before I left home no longer works.  Apparently it has expired.  Can I still access the computer?

Answer (score 4):

To connect remotely to a computer running TeamViewer you enter an ID Number, unique to each host computer, and a Password, a randomly generated code.  The ID is always the same for the same computer but the password changes every time the host computer starts the program.

This is perfect for doing remote tech support because the host (the customer) must give the new password to the support person (connecting remotely) every time.

When using TeamViewer to access your own computer remotely, you can set a password of your choosing to be used instead of the randomly generated password code.  That password will remain in effect permanently unless you change it.

Just click "Configure permanent access..." as shown below to set your permanent password. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually a password will only expire if the computer is part of a domain and a domain policy is set to enforce changing a password. If this is the case, you can only get into the computer again by plugging the pc back into the network where it was part of the domain, then login using your old password and when it tells you to change the password, change it.

If you have another user that you could login with that has administrative privileges, you can use that user to reset the users password.

EDIT: It appears the question is about teamviewer. This information was not added when posting this answer, so I didn't know it was about teamviewer. For the sake of history of this problem, I'll leave the answer + comments in tact.

Comment: I agree, but the wording suggests that the user just forgot the password.  "Apparently it has expired" suggests that the user thinks that the password can expire on it's own.  and this is a home computer, there is less of a chance that there is an AD account setup for this computer.  I think it is a forgotten password situation.  or typing in the password incorrectly.   other than that I agree with you

Comment: also the password will work after the user leaves the network until they connect to the network again.  the password won't expire while the computer is not connected to the network.

Comment: The computer is not part of a domain -- it is my home computer.  I am new to TeamViewer so not sure I understand all the details yet.  I wrote down the password I set before I left home, but it no longer works.  (It worked yesterday.)

Comment: what do you mean TeamViewer, @Margie?

Comment: TeamViewer is the remote access program I am using. Their site led me to you to post my question. Sorry if I am in the wrong place!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion -- I thought this was a TeamViewer site.  I just spoke to them and they say that the password is dynamic and changes "all the time."  Unfortunately, I can't access my home computer without physically changing the password at that location.  However, TeamViewer still seems to be a good program for remote access.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: @Margie - Your question is perfectly appropriate for this site!  The comments above are confusing the TeamViewer password with the unrelated Windows user password.  See my answer below.

Comment: Also, you failed to mention it was about teamviewer before, which is why my solution was not directed at teamviewer.